# Editar última fila con valores en VBA Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Básicamente necesito editar la última fila con valores existentes de otra hoja, es decir, posicionarse en la última fila que tenga algún valor y copiar un valor desde un formulario, para luego ejecutar el código de abajo y agregar valores a una nueva fila. (no estoy usando userform, solamente un formulario creado en las celdas de Excel)[image]

Por ejemplo, necesito dejar pagada la operación anterior, para luego crear y pegar valores en la nueva fila que estoy creando con el codigo que deje abajo, en este caso sería poner la P en el 297 para luego crear como lo estoy haciendo la 298

Sub Guardar2()

```
Sheets("abono").Activate
Range("C4").Copy

Sheets("pagares").Activate
Range("B1").Select
columna = Selection.End(xlDown).Row + 1 'guia para todos los demas'

Sheets("abono").Activate 'pagado
Range("C24").Copy 'cambiar c4'
Sheets("pagares").Activate
Cells(columna, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'cambiar 1 por la fila a pegar'

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("pagares").ListObjects("Tabla1").Sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("pagares").ListObjects("Tabla1").Sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("Tabla1[[#All],[Pagare_Asoc]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("pagares").ListObjects("Tabla1").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Tu manera de conseguir la última fila no vacía es incorrecta.

`columna = Selection.End(xlDown).Row + 1` esto lo que hace es que, partiendo de B1, se detiene donde encuentre la última celda en blanco. Pero no tiene por qué ser la última fila. Imagina que te saltas alguna celda o algo.

Todo esto:

```
Sheets("pagares").Activate
Range("B1").Select
columna = Selection.End(xlDown).Row + 1 'guia para todos los demas'

Sheets("abono").Activate 'pagado
Range("C24").Copy 'cambiar c4'
Sheets("pagares").Activate
Cells(columna, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'cambiar 1 por la fila a pegar'
```

Se puede resumir en:

```
With Sheets("pagares")
    columna = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

Sheets("abono").Range("C24").Copy
Sheets("pagares").Cells(columna, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Prueba y nos dices.